# Insert different type of entities in GAE using JPA

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am new to GAE and Datastore

I am trying to insert different types of entities in GAE Datastore using JPA.
For example i have to insert Employee,EmployeePersonalInfo(Having a Employee Key),EmployeeAddressInfo(Having a EmployeePersonalInfo key). Here i am not creating any foreign key relationships between entities.My entities will looks like follows

```
public class Employee{

private String name;
private Key key;
}

public class EmployeePersonalInfo{
private String emailAddress;
private Key key;
private Key employeeKey;
}

public class EmployeeAddressInfo{
private String cityName;
private Key key;
private Key employeePersonalInfoKey;
}

i am trying to insert around 5 record on each table like

public class EmployeeController{

/*This method will be called for 5 times*/
public void insertEmployeeDetails(Employee emp,EmployeePersonalInfo perInfo,EmployeeAddressInfo addressInfo){
employeeDao.save(emp);
employeePersonalInfoDao.save(perInfo);
employeeAddressInfoDao.save(addressInfo);
}
}
```

Every time When a call goes to Save method of the DAO classes i will open the EntityManager object , and close after the operation.

```
public void save(Employee emp){
        EntityManager em = EMFService.get().createEntityManager();
                em.save(emp);
                em.close();

}
```

Here sometimes i am getting an exception like

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cross-group transaction need to be explicitly specified, see TransactionOptions.Builder.withXG
```

I have seen my so many solutions to this problem but i am not able to understand what is the real problem and solution. Please help me